# The behavior of varnish on MISS

Tags: varnish

Consider this scenario:
The Varnish cache has a MISS and the backend server is now regenerating the requested content. During the generation time a second request comes in and also gets an MISS. Does varnish send this request to the backend while the other request is pending? What if thousand requests come in between this time. Server would crash right? Every request would make it slower.

Is this correct or is varnish "synchronizing" those scenarios to prevent such a problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varnish sends all the requests to the backend. I.e. it does not queue other requests and issue just one backend request and use its response for all.

However Varnish has a [grace option](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleGrace) that lets you keep old, expired content in cache for these types of situations.

For example consider the following VCL:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  if (req.backend.healthy) {
    set req.grace = 5m;
  } else {
    set req.grace = 24h;
  }
}

sub vcl_fetch {
   set beresp.grace = 24h;
}
```

Now if a backend is healthy (see [backend polling](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/BackendPolling)) and a request results in a `MISS`, the first request is sent to a backend. If another request comes for the same content, but there is an item in the cache with age <TTL+req.grace (in this case 5 minutes), that request will get the "stale" content instead. This happens as long as either the first request that resulted in a `MISS` gets a response from the backend (and the cache is fresh again) or the age of the item becomes greater than TTL+req.grace.

If the backend was down (req.backend.healthy == FALSE), stale content would be served as long as age<TTL+24h.

You might also want to check out the [Saving a request](https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/Saving_a_request.html) section of the [Varnish book](https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/) for a more thorough example and an exercise.

**Fixed:** unescaped < character.

**Fixed more:** There was another unescaped < character...

Comment: I noticed that I had an unescaped < character in my answer. Fixed now. Didn't make much sense before. =)

Comment: Hmm still I have the question what will happend if the cache is empty after a blackout or crash. our sites are heavily visited resulting in many requests per second. I think it could kill our webservers if varnish has an empty cache. Thats the reason why there is my hope that varnish will let equal requests wait and and only perform it once. the others will get their answer from cache after that. so the servers would do a request like the homepage only once. and not 1000 times in parallel. any ideas about this issue?

Comment: As I read until now it will deliver old content within gracetime. therewhile varnish tries to update the cache with an request made to the backend. when the cache is updated varnish will deliver the actual content for the request on new requests. so it does not queue them until the cache has been renewed. after the lifetime plus the gracetime of an object are in the past varnish will not deliver anything from cache and it tries to ask the backend. your backend should be really be able to deliver the requested content within gracetime.

Comment: for an url update varnish does not send multiple reqs in parallel to the backends. that would produce silly load on the webserver and slow down things. if I'm false please correct me!

Comment: If you wish to expand your question, please consider either editing the original question or posting a new one. If I understood your comment correctly, you are asking what happens within the grace period. After cached object expires (object age is greater than TTL), Client#1 gets his request sent to the backend while Client#2-n get the cached version. In the example above Client#1 should get his/her response within 5 minutes. If it takes longer than that, you should really consider other ways of speeding up your pages.

Comment: I believe Varnish will indeed queue requests.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Ketola's (accepted) answer is wrong.

Multiple requests to Varnish for the same URI **will** be queued.

Then it depends if the result of the first request is cacheable or not. If it is, it will be used for other (queued) requests as well.
If not, all other queued requests will be sent to the backend.

So if you have some slow API endpoint you want to cache, and it's cacheable (regarding Varnish rules), multiple requests will hit the backend only once for that URI.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the points or whatever to comment on @max_i's answer so I'm submitting another answer to verify his instead.

Ketola's accepted answer isn't completely wrong, it's possibly just out of date, and may have been true for older versions of Varnish. Specifically this part:

> Varnish sends all the requests to the backend. I.e. it does not queue other requests and issue just one backend request and use its response for all.

After independently testing this myself using a standard installation of Varnish 4.1 LTS and Apache 2.4, I created a basic PHP file which contained the following:

```
<?php sleep(5); echo 'hello world!';
```

Then used [ab](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) to test the HTTP request cycle using 50 requests at 5 concurrency. The results showed that while Varnish accepted every single connection, only one request was ever made to the backend, which, as expected, took roughly 5 seconds to resolve. Each Varnish connection subsequently had to wait that minimum period before receiving a response.

The downside to this is of course that requests after the first one are "queued" behind it, but this is of course a minor concern compared to all 50 requests hitting the backend at once (or in the case of my test, with a concurrency of 5).